# Function that creates a dataframe out of a regression

Tags: r, function

I'd like to write a function that returns a data frame of length N that looks as follows

```
y     x1     x2
14.84 -1.62 -0.39
9.72 -0.15 -1.83
9.40 1.08 -0.76
...
13.36 0.26 0.49
```

I'm a beginner - so I'd be happy if someone can bring me back on track. I have the following code, but I don't know how I can safe my `x1`, `x2` and `y1` into such a dataframe.
My code:

```
DataFrame(alpha, beta1, beta2, sigma, n){
  x1 <- runif(n, min = -10, max = 10)
  x2 <- runif(n, min = -10, max = 10)
  y1 <- as.vector(alpha + x1*beta1 + x2*beta2)
  dataframe <- as.data.frame()

  return(dataframe)
}
```

Comment: almost there `DataFrame <- function(alpha, beta1, beta2, sigma, n){...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to assign your function definition to `DataFrame` first. Also your `as.data.frame()` statement is empty!

```
DataFrame <- function(alpha, beta1, beta2, sigma, n){
  x1 <- runif(n, min = -10, max = 10)
  x2 <- runif(n, min = -10, max = 10)
  y1 <- as.vector(alpha + x1*beta1 + x2*beta2)
  dataframe <- cbind.data.frame(y = y1, x1 = x1, x2 = x2)

  return(dataframe)
}
```

Comment: You should use `data.frame` instead of `cbind`.

Comment: I second Roland's suggestion.  `cbind` doesn't create a data.frame.  In this case it doesn't matter since everything is numeric but still...